# Multiple response question with duplicated answers

Tags: spss

I have a multiple response (categories) question (Q11, ..., Q15). My problem is that the data-entry clerck repeats the answers in the same case.

Example:

```
       Q11 Q12 Q13 Q14 Q15
Case 1 001 003 015 001 022 (001 was type twice)
Case 2 089 032 089 089 014 (089 was typed three times)
```

I need to find a way to identified the cases with these errors.

Thanks,

Comment: How do you know which are errors? E.g. if the question was "What would did you eat for breakfast?" and the answers recorded were "sausage, egg, bacon, sausage, tomato", are you simply not interested whether the person really ate two sausages or only one sausage?

Comment: Is this a question about statistical analysis or is it about obtaining a software algorithm to screen duplicate values?  Could you clarify your intent?